# Wordpress how to get a category from products that are present in another specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I have clothes products. One product is in multiples categories, like "gender" ("men" or "women") and "type" (such as "pants", "shirts", etc.).

I want to list all categories and subcategories of "type" from products that exist in "men" category.

ID of "type" category: 1696

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
  'orderby'  => 'title',
  'order'    => 'ASC',
  'child_of'   => 1696,
);
$categories = get_terms( $args );
print_r($categories);
```

That code gives me all the categories under 1696, but I would like to get only the "type" categories from products that also are in "men" category.

Am I clear?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since wordpress only allows one id at a time for `child_of` argument, you could create a custom array and run `get_terms` for every parent category that you want.

> From the documentation:
>
> - `child_of` - (int) Term ID to retrieve child terms of. **If multiple taxonomies are passed**, $child_of is ignored. Default **0**.
>   [wp_term_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)

```php
$child_cats = array();

$parent_cats = array(1696, {the other category id});

$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
  'orderby'  => 'title',
  'order'    => 'ASC',
  'child_of'=> $parent_cat
);

foreach ($parent_cats as $parent_cat) 
{
    $child_cats = array_merge($child_cats, get_terms($args));
};

print_r($child_cats);
```

Let me know if that's what you were looking for!

Comment: I don't understand what the code you suggest is doing. And the $args array with "'child_of'=> $parent_cat" shouldn't be inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Basically it'll get you an array with all of the subcategories that you wanted. We're calling `$args` inside the loop. If you don't understand it, that's ok, you will, once you gain more experience in coding. And you don't have to use the code i've provided you with. There are other ways to do the same thing, you could write code that is two pages long to achieve the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but it's not what I need.

I found a way to achieve what I want. There must be a better way but here's how I did:

I'm looping every products and put them in arrays if they are in the gender category ("femme" and "homme").

```
    $categories_femme = array(); // 1718
    $categories_homme = array(); // 1700
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ): while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();

      global $product;

      $p_id = $product->get_id();
      
      // FEMME
      if( has_term( 1718, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $categories_femme[] = wp_get_post_terms($p_id, 'product_cat');
      }
      // HOMME
      if( has_term( 1700, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $categories_homme[] = wp_get_post_terms($p_id, 'product_cat');
      }

    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

After that, I'm formating the array to get this structure of categories (one array per gender): array('term_id' => 'name_id', 'term_id' => 'name_id', 'term_id' => 'name_id');

```
    $categories_femme_formated = array();
    foreach ($categories_femme as $categorie_femme) {
      foreach ($categorie_femme as $categoriefemme) {
        $categories_femme_formated[$categoriefemme->term_id] = $categoriefemme->name;
      }
    }
    
    $categories_homme_formated = array();
    foreach ($categories_homme as $categorie_homme) {
      foreach ($categorie_homme as $categoriehomme) {
        $categories_homme_formated[$categoriehomme->term_id] = $categoriehomme->name;
      }
    }
```

After that, I'm looping through all clothes categories and looking if this category ID exist in the array created just before. If yes, I'm adding this category to the menu.

```
    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'parent'   => 1696
    );
    $product_cat = get_terms( $args );

    // FEMME
    $count_order = 100;
    foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
    {
      $p_id = $parent_product_cat->term_id;
      if (array_key_exists($p_id, $categories_femme_formated)) {
        $count_order++;
        $menu_items[] = _custom_nav_menu_item( $categories_femme_formated[$p_id], get_term_link($p_id), $count_order, 11407 );
        
        $child_args = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
            );
        $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
        $parent_order = $count_order;
        foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
        {
          $c_id = $child_product_cat->term_id;
          if (array_key_exists($c_id, $categories_femme_formated)) {
            $count_order++;
            $child_menu_id = 1000000 + $parent_order + 11407;
            $menu_items[] = _custom_nav_menu_item( $categories_femme_formated[$c_id], get_term_link($c_id), $count_order, $child_menu_id );
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    // HOMME
    $count_order = 100;
    foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
    {
      $p_id = $parent_product_cat->term_id;
      if (array_key_exists($p_id, $categories_homme_formated)) {
        $count_order++;
        $menu_items[] = _custom_nav_menu_item( $categories_homme_formated[$p_id], get_term_link($p_id), $count_order, 11408 );
        
        $child_args = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
            );
        $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
        $parent_order = $count_order;
        foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
        {
          $c_id = $child_product_cat->term_id;
          if (array_key_exists($c_id, $categories_homme_formated)) {
            $count_order++;
            $child_menu_id = 1000000 + $parent_order + 11408;
            $menu_items[] = _custom_nav_menu_item( $categories_homme_formated[$c_id], get_term_link($c_id), $count_order, $child_menu_id );
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Just for everyone to understand, I'm calling this code inside a function called by:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items' );
```

And here is the _custom_nav_menu_item function:

```
function _custom_nav_menu_item( $title, $url, $order, $parent = 0 ){
  $item = new stdClass();
  $item->ID = 1000000 + $order + $parent;
  $item->db_id = $item->ID;
  $item->title = $title;
  $item->url = $url;
  $item->menu_order = $order;
  $item->menu_item_parent = $parent;
  $item->type = '';
  $item->object = '';
  $item->object_id = '';
  $item->classes = array();
  $item->target = '';
  $item->attr_title = '';
  $item->description = '';
  $item->xfn = '';
  $item->status = '';
  $item->icon = '';
  $item->nolink = '';
  $item->hide = '';
  $item->mobile_hide = ''; 
  $item->cols = ''; 
  $item->tip_label = '';
  $item->popup_type = 'wide';
  $item->popup_pos = '';
  $item->popup_cols = 'col-4';
  $item->popup_max_width = '';
  $item->popup_bg_image = '';
  $item->popup_bg_pos = ''; 
  $item->popup_bg_repeat = ''; 
  $item->popup_bg_size = ''; 
  $item->popup_style = '';
  $item->block = '';
  $item->preview = '';
  $item->preview_fixed = ''; 
  $item->current = '';
  $item->current_item_ancestor = '';
  $item->current_item_parent = '';
  return $item;
}
```

Thanks again for your help.  :)